How to tell if my CPU has FMA3?
An upcoming upgrade to a critical program I use will require AVX2 and FMA3. My Intel processor supports AVX2 as listed on the intel site's specs for my CPU (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4771 CPU @ 3.50GHz) but no mention of FMA3.
I randomly checked other newer processors and could find no mention of FMA3.
Any ideas on how to determine if I have FMA3? Is this part of AVX2? Or been around for so long no one mentions it separately?

in windows i would check CPU-Z, or in linux use sudo lshw -c CPU. Wikipedia implies that FMA3 is sometimes assumed to be part/party to AVX2, since both were released for the Haswell architecture (which your chip uses). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#Advanced_Vector_Extensions_2

The Wikipedia entry for FMA instructions set should tell you everything you need to know.
It starts with the definition:

The FMA instruction set is an extension to the 128 and 256-bit Streaming SIMD Extensions instructions in the x86 microprocessor instruction set to perform fused multiply–add (FMA) operations.

Later it shows all the CPU that have it, AMD and Intel. Relevant to this question is the mention:

Haswell (2013) and newer processors, except Pentiums and Celerons

So, your Intel® Core™ i7-4771 Processor, being of the Haswell family, was one of the first Intel CPUs to support it.
FMA3 is not "part of" the Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (AVX2) but they are contemporary features. AVX2 and FMA3 were both introduced in the same Intel CPU generation but the former is also available in more recent Celerons, as stated:


Haswell processors (Q2 2013) and newer, except models branded as Celeron and Pentium.
Celeron and Pentium branded processors starting with Tiger Lake (Q3 2020) and newer.



Building  on both ChanganAuto's answer and Frank Thomas' comment - you can query  the computer itself.
On linux - lshw will work, and will show it as FMA (I'm unsure/unable to check what I'll show FMA4 as), and on windows cpu-z or other tools would show this.
On a supposedly supported 4th generation CPU - a haswell Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4010U this is the lshw -c cpu output

capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq

You've not mentioned the OS - so I'll give examples of the results for windows and linux
I have n100s running linux and windows, and so can confirm that the cpu-z entry for FMA3 is what lshw refers to as fma.

And the corresponding lshw output

